# .NET Core solution versions

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm learning how to build .NET Core apps from scratch. Being curious, I created an empty solution via Visual Studio 2019, and it gave me this version at the top of the .sln file:

```
# Visual Studio Version 16
VisualStudioVersion = 16.0.29215.179
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

Then, for comparison's sake, I created one using `dotnet new sln` and got this version:

```
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
```

It looks to me like my version of the CLI tooling is using older VS 2017 templates, but I'm stumped if I need to install updated tooling or update the templates. As far as I can tell, I'm using the latest tooling, but this is new to me, so maybe I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: The `.sln` file is almost entirely irrelevant, though, and does not actually specify any .NET Core tooling version -- unless there's actually going to be multiple projects, a typical .NET Core app could just live as one project with no solution. I'm not even quite sure why `dotnet new sln` exists, as it's more a Visual Studio thing than anything else... probably for completeness' sake.

Comment: dotnet.exe has no knowledge of what VS version you are using.  It is meant as an *alternative* to VS, useful in particular to Unix devs that can't run VS.  If you have VS then you can get very far without ever having to run it explicitly.  Winning the hearts and minds of Unix devs is import to Microsoft, in practice I think a lot of them favor using vscode over jockeying the cli, its been quite a hit.

Comment: Thank you both. Makes sense and I won't get hung up on the differences.